# Trying to execute a shell script from Swift 5 code but to no avail

Tags: swift, shell

Every tutorial I looked at as well as Apple docs, they all suggest instantiating the Process object, for the purpose of running a shell script from Swift code.

However when I do:

`let task = Process()`

in Swift 5, The compiler then complains that this line can't be compiled because of:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Process'

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: You forgot to import Foundation

Comment: I added the import statement already but it doesn't solve any thing unfortunately.